# Spring: DRY with <list/>. Copy all values from listA to listB

Tags: java, spring, ioc-container, dry

I've configured  in Spring listA (see below). It would be nice to have another one that contains all values from listA and expand it.

```
<bean id="listA" class="java.util.ArrayList">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <value>a</value>
            <value>b</value>
            <value>...</value>
            <value>z</value>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

How to rewrite in Spring such Java code?

```
    List listB = new ArrayList(listA);
    listB.add("A");
    ...
    listB.add("Z");
```

Comment: Don't rewrite the Java in XML - just use Java (http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [collection merging](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-collection-elements-merging):

```
<bean id="listA" class="java.util.ArrayList">
    <constructor-arg index="0">
        <list>
            <value>a</value>
            <value>b</value>
            <value>...</value>
            <value>z</value>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="listB" parent="listA">
    <constructor-arg index="0">
        <list merge="true">
            <value>A</value>
            <value>...</value>
            <value>Z</value>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```